# Trying to add row to database on function call in php using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

Here is the code I am using.  I have verified I am connecting to the database by manually adding a row to the table and selecting it.  I just can't seem to find what is wrong.  I hope I am not overlooking something simple and wasting everyone's time.  Be gentle with me I am super new.  I do get the error message when it tries to add the query.

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','trackday')
or die('Cannot connect to database');

$query = "INSERT INTO horses(color, gate_speed, sprint_speed, middle_speed,                 
    jockey_response, final_burst, finishing_speed)" .
"VALUES('$horseColor', '$gateSpeed', '$sprintSpeed', '$middleSpeed',
    '$jockeyResponse', $finalBurst', '$finishingSpeed');";


$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
or die("Error adding horse");
```

Comment: It doesn't insert the row.

Comment: `'$jockeyResponse', $finalBurst', '$finishingSpeed');";` <-- syntax error. Missing `'` before `$finalBurst'`.

Comment: *"I do get the error message when it tries to add the query."* - Being? I know it but you could post it.

Comment: @briosheje +1 You should've put one in. `$one="answer";` ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- : for such cases I just care to **help** the user, I don't think I deserve any reputation point for such a syntax error :)

Comment: @briosheje Yes, I do the same thing as well, unless the OP wants the question closed due to a comment fixing the actual error or if I spent 1/2 hour on debugging/testing; quite noble of you :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- : let's hope that this is the **only** error. We don't know the structure of the database table and we don't even know where the variables are coming from.. so.. who knows :P maybe this is just the tip of the iceberg :P

Comment: @briosheje You've made a very good point there ;) `$tip_of_iceberg="Can of worms?";`

Comment: `or die('Cannot connect to database');` don't make it die like that, get the real error `or die(mysqli_error())` including `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` if you're not already doing so.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : Whatever, now let's hope that the user is not dead or suppressed either by the can of worms or the tip of the iceberg, lol. Maybe, someday, he will tell us if it is working. :P

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following format to prevent yourself from falling victim to Query Injection

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','trackday')
or die('Cannot connect to database');

if($stmt = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO horses(color, gate_speed, sprint_speed, middle_speed,jockey_response, final_burst, finishing_speed) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"))
{
$stmt->bind_param('sssssss',$horseColor, $gateSpeed, $sprintSpeed, $middleSpeed, $jockeyResponse, $finalBurst, $finishingSpeed);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
printf("Error Adding Horse: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO horses(color, gate_speed, sprint_speed, middle_speed,                 
jockey_response, final_burst, finishing_speed) " .
"VALUES('" . $horseColor . "' , '". $gateSpeed . "', '" . $sprintSpeed . "', '" . $middleSpeed . "', '" . $jockeyResponse . "', '" . $finalBurst . "', '" . $finishingSpeed ."');";
```

You should also consider using [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to keep you save from [SQL injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: Man, you have a syntax error here too. please **CHECK** before posting: `"' . $finalBurst . "'` should be `"' . $finalBurst . '"`

Comment: The *"Does this work for you?"* answers, doesn't let the OP know where the code is failing. Question is, did it work for "you"?

Comment: miron: won't help preventing injectons if you don't write the query correctly.

Comment: Oh gosh Miron... ty ty I feel so stupid.  Thanks for the tip about the injections.  This was my first attempt at writing it so I was just trying to get it functioning.